When does the degree of serial correlation in a predictor become problematic when using Monte Carlo perm test to determine significant of returns?
When does the degree of serial correlation in a predictor become problematic when using a Monte Carlo permutation test (resampling test) to determine the significance of trading returns?
Take an exaggerated case where over the entire sample, the predictor is highly serially correlated. Then maybe there are clusters of returns for which the predictor yields positive returns. Also the series will look like a non stationary series, when perhaps over a long enough time period it would be stationary.
